# How clearing cache solves all your problems?

Tags: applications, delete, cache

My phone is Android A30s. I recently have encountered two problems: I couldn't download an application from appstore and I couldn't open the Yahoo app. Both problems I solved by deleting the cache from the respective apps. The question is: how does it work? How deleting the cache resolved these two problems, exactly? Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the tag wiki of [cache tag you used?](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/cache/info)

Comment: I did now, but it still doesn't explain the mechanisms I'm looking for..

Comment: *corrupted app data* is cleared and the app responds as it should (when you clear cache)//If your doubt is why does app data get corrupt? That's a good question and should be a separately asked

Comment: Thank you so much!